# Can one inspect Passkeys on iCloud Keychain

Tags: keychain, icloud

So Apple [syncs FIDO Passkeys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213305) across a user's devices using iCloud Keychain.

Can one inspect those Passkeys in ones own iCloud Keychain e.g. with the macOS app *Keychain Access*? I have tried with version 11.0 on macOS 13.1, but don't yet see any entries that seem related to the authenticators that were registered with a WebAuthn demo in Safari 16.2.

Comment: What do you want to “inspect?”  It’s an encrypted key so anything you see in it will be gibberish.

Comment: I assume they want to view the raw key, like one can do with 1Password...

Comment: @Allan It would be enough for me (and for now) to see the entries among the various other credentials stored there. I other words, I'd be happy to do "`ls`" without "`cat`".

Comment: So, you want to *list* the passkeys stored in your keychain versus read the contents of the keys themselves?

Comment: @Allen Ideally both, but listing them clearly comes first (and reading the content may not even be possible because of the applied encryption, etc.)